# Stongly tamasic family member

Tags: gunas

My only son (33 years now) is very strongly tamasic due to not listening to parents, teachers, and other well wishers. He wastes all his time in "pramaad" and not ready to do any useful activity even neglecting to earn money for his own living, forget about his wife and his newly born son. He is financially dependent on me and his wife. He doesn't take smallest responsibility also.
When we try to advise him (peacefully), he trashes it and avoids us. There is a long list. We have done many anushthans to repair his "buddhi". Still no success.
Kindly guide what should we do. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you seek astrological advice from genuine experts and do some remedies they suggest? Why someone is behaving in a particular way can be best understood by studying their horoscope (Dashas that are currently etc.). And once the problem is rectified at the astrological level behavior will improve.